# Raise Events from SignalR Hub

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, signalr, signalr-hub

I want to be able to notify my Web API controller after the SignalR Hub received a message from a client and finished processing.  My first thought is raising an event and have an event handler on the web api controller to respond to that.  Is this something feasible, or if not, are there any alternatives I can consider other than polling?

Comment: Your server hub lives in the web api stack that you mention or is it inside another application?

Comment: Hi ibubi, the server hub is inside the web api stack.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Service Bus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_service_bus) and kind of worker to dispatch notifications from SignalR(RabbitMQ, MSMQ or anything similar). You can place that dispatcher separately from Web API logic and call API from it, or you can implement the whole logic in it, avoiding API interaction at all.

Placing an event handler on API level is a bad idea, because that approach messes logic of controllers.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, it sounds like you need a *reusable* helper class/method which will be using from a controller action and a signal server method both.

#### Helper Class

```
public static class TestHelper
{
    public TestHelper()
    {
    }

    public static void DoSomething()
    {
        //Consumed by multiple places
    }
}
```

#### Controller

```
public class UserController : ApiController
{

    public IHttpActionResult Post(User user)
    {
        //Controller logic
        TestHelper.DoSomething();

    }
}
```

#### Server Hub

```
public class MyHub : Hub
{
    //Consumed by signlar clients
    public static void ServerHubMethod()
    {
        IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyHub>();

        //Other logic 

        TestHelper.DoSomething();

    }
}
```

I think this way builds more reusable and readable code.